# MS Excel - Apply Validation To Cell After User has Pasted

Tags: excel, validation, vba

Is there a way to get cell validation to trigger when pasting to a cell in Excel?

For example I have a cell that only accepts an input of 10 characters, and if it goes beyond you can't enter.

1234A12345

But if I paste, it overrides the validation rule.

1234A12345/001

I'd ideally like to keep the ability to paste for this specific column table, as I have users entering 10s of rows of data, and i don't want them to manually input them every time.

Thanks!

Comment: your best bet in that case is to instead have them paste special -> values and instead of relying on data validation (which won't trigger on a paste operation), instead use conditional formatting to turn cells red that don't meet requirements

Comment: If you need the pasted values to automatically be truncated to 10 characters, that would require VBA, specifically the [Worksheet_Change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel)